# anchor link work on desktop/pc but not on mobile

Tags: html

I am trying to create links to an anchor on the same page.

On desktop/PC it works normally, however, on my iPhone and mobiles the same does not work, you click on them, and nothing happens.

```
<img id="anchor" src="link_to_image.jpg">
```

this is the anchor

```
<a href="#anchor">link to anchor</a>
```

and that's the link to anchor

however, on mobile it doesn't work, clicking on the link nothing happens.

Any suggestions?

EDIT

It seems that, when i load the page on mobile, the tag "id=#anchor" disappear from the images.

Instead of this:

```
<img id="anchor" src="link_to_image.jpg">
```

It becomes this:

```
<img src="link_to_image.jpg">
```

Why the "id" tag gets removed from the images on mobile?

Comment: Perhaps there are two `<img src="link_to_image.jpg">`  in the page, they display in different screen width. Or the js scrips hide the original `<img>`, then recreate another in small screen. The info is not enough to know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<a href="#anchor">link to anchor</a>

<img id="anchor" src="link_to_image.jpg">
```

Try this:

```
<a href="#anchor">link to anchor</a>


<a name="anchor"><img src="link_to_image.jpg"></a>
```

This is the older/ more traditional way to do it and it might work differently on a mobile device.